# why is there def enter(self): function in all the classes of ex43.py of LPTHW that's never called anywhere in the whole project?

Tags: python

i am on exercise 43 from Learn Python The Hard Way by Zed Shaw. There are so many things i don't get but they are here or there been asked in different forums. what i didn't get here is in the following code excerpts:

```
class Scene(object):

def enter(self):
    print("This scene is not yet configured.")
    print("Subclass it and implement and enter().")
    exit(1)
```

this enter(self) has been defined in almost all the classes of the project. but i don't see it being called anywhere. what's its purpose?

```
class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene):

def enter(self):
    print(dedent("""
        You do a dive roll into the Weapon Armory, crouch and scan 
        the room for more Gothons that might be hiding. It's dead 
        quiet, too quiet. You stand up and run to the far side of 
        the room and find the neutron bomb in its container. 
        There's a keypad lock on the box and you need the code to 
        get the bomb out. If you get the cod e wrong 10 times then 
        the lock closes forever and you can't get the bomb. The 
        code is 3 digits. 
        """))

    code = f"{randint(1,9)}{randint(1, 9)}{randint(1, 9)}"
    guess = input("[keypad]> ")
    guesses = 0

    while guess != code and guesses < 10:
        print("BUZZZZZED!")
        guesses += 1
        guess = input("[keypad]> ")

    if guess == code:
        print(dedent("""
            The container clicks open and the seal breaks, letting 
            gas out. You grab the neutron bomb and run as fast as 
            you can to the bridge where you must place it in the 
            right spot.
            #########
            """))
        return 'the_bridge'
    else:
        print(dedent("""
            The lock buzzes one last time and then you hear a
            sickening melting sound as the mechanism is fused 
            together. You decide to sit there, and finally the 
            Gothons blow up the ship from their ship and you die.
            """))
        return 'death'
```

i found similar things called context manager: **enter**, though i still dont understant what that mean as i am just a beginner.
please explain each of them, if different, differently.
thank you

Comment: There is context missing. This `enter` function is part of the interface specific to `Scene`, and is not related to the `__enter__` method that needs to be defined on context managers (which are a really neat feature, BTW). There is some call to `enter` in some code that uses the polymorphic `Scene` class hierarchy -you just need to find it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would help if you explained what you _do_ understand about the code provided, as it is right now, the question is very broad. `Scene` is a _class_, `LaserWeaponArmory` is a _subclass_ of `Scene`. Both have the `enter()` _class method_ defined. These keywords, class, subclass, class method (and superclass) should help guide your research, but this question is hard to answer in a meaningful way

Comment: One example you might try is to define your own subclass of `Scene`, like `class EmptyRoom(Scene):pass` then create an instance like `myroom=EmptyRoom()` and see what happens when you call `myroom.enter()`

Comment: What makes you think `.enter()` is not being called?  I'm pretty sure that if you ran this code, you would be seeing the text that is printed by the methods.  (And there is absolutely no connection with the `.__enter__()` of context managers - why would there be, those aren't the same name at all.)

Comment: @jasonharper, you seem to be correct. it should have been called anywhere in the whole project which i am missing. need more working on class and methods i guess. thank you.